# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'toarray'

Tags: attributes, attributeerror, topic-modeling, toarray, latent-semantic-analysis

I tried to solve this issue but the error keeps persistent. It is not a problem for English texts, but it is so for Arabic. Any idea how to solve this problem?

```
top_n_words_lsa = get_top_n_words(10, lsa_keys, small_document_term_matrix, small_count_vectorizer)

for i in range(len(top_n_words_lsa)):
    print("Topic {}: ".format(i+1), top_n_words_lsa[i])
```

---

AttributeError: `int` object has no attribute `toarray`